# Pourquoi le français, très largement issu du latin, est-il toujours allé, au fil des siècles, dans le sens d'une complication de la grammaire ?

Tags: grammaire, linguistique, latin, évolution

D'emblée, il est apparent que la grammaire latine est bien plus simple que la française.

Les déclinaisons, qui constituent la difficulté majeure de la première, y ont certes virtuellement disparu, mais au prix de la nécessité de mettre un article, et de figer l'ordre des mots.

Le latin est bien plus concis, et tout autant précis, sans lourdes paraphrases ; par exemple :

- « *Qu'est-ce c'est que ça ?* » s'écrit « *Quid est hoc ?* »
- « *trucidare, rapere, falsis nomibus imperium* » signifie « massacrer, piller, voilà ce que l'on appelle fallacieusement régner sur un empire ».

Le français doit détenir le record mondial du nombre de verbes irréguliers, rangés dans le fourre-tout du 3ème groupe (auquel appartient le redoutable « aller ») : 570 ! (anglais : 283 ; allemand : 170 ; espagnol : 46).

Accessoirement, pourquoi des bizarreries d'orthographe sans justification : « bonhomie », « des choux », « banal » qui a deux pluriels selon le sens, etc. Moyen redoutable, avec les règles de liaison (compter par exemple : *un N œuf, deux Z œufs, … neuf V œufs, etc.*), de discerner le niveau de « culture » d'une personne (en anglais, c'est essentiellement l'accent).

Pourquoi donc, par quel mécanisme, être constamment allé dans le sens de la complication ?

Comment: Et dans quel état serait le latin s'il n'était pas mort?

Comment: D'où tires-tu ces nombres de verbes irréguliers ? En l'état ça me semble moyennement pertinent si on ne prend pas en compte leur fréquence d'emploi. Par exemple [*comparoir*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/comparoir) existe, mais comme il ne sert jamais… Et si tu compare à l'italien ou ) l'espagnol, les irrégularités y sont bien pires.

Comment: @Evpok Le décompte a été fait dans Wikipedia. Les verbes irréguliers sont souvent les plus usuels, c'est clair particulièrement en anglais, et le sont restés précisément parce qu'ils étaient usuels. J'ai étudié espagnol et italien après avoir appris le français (naturellement), ai d'abord été étonné par les professeurs déclarant que c'était bien pire en français, ai vérifié, et ils ont raison. En employant un verbe aussi courant que "aller", je ne m'étais même pas aperçu qu'il était complètement irrégulier et n'appartenait pas au 1er groupe.

Comment: @Evpok J'ai laissé passer : comparoir est défectif, mais pas irrégulier pour la bonne raison qu'il ne s'emploie qu'à l'infinitif - et ce, encore maintenant dans les milieux juridiques.

Comment: Il serait intéressant aussi de comparer le nombre de verbes irréguliers au nombre total de verbes dans chaque langue.

Comment: Le verbe aller est tout aussi irrégulier en espagnol, anglais, italien ...

Answer (score 2):

À propos de la concision du latin et de la complexité du français. On ne peut pas opposer concision et complexité. Concision s'opposerait plutôt à redondance. Or, un minimum de redondance grammaticale, voire stylistique, est nécessaire pour rendre le langage plus facilement intelligible, et, il me semble, pour faire passer plus d'intentions et émotions. À ce niveau, le latin est certainement moins efficace que le français: le français n'irai donc pas dans le sens de la complication...

Answer (score 2):

L'évolution vers la complexité n'est pas systématique ou même avérée.

La proportion de verbes irréguliers a tendance a diminuer, les néologismes verbaux étant majoritairement du premier groupe sauf quand ils sont calqués sur un verbe établi (ex: ***alunir***).

"***Quid est hoc ?***" se dit le plus souvent aujourd'hui "***C'est quoi ?***" ou "***C'est quoi ça ?***".

L'ordre des mots n'est peut-être pas si important puisque cette dernière expression devient parfois "***Quoi c'est ?***" écrit "***koi c***" qui bat à plates coutures le latin en terme de simplicité comme de concision  **;-)**

---

PS: Tacite a écrit: "trucidare, rapere, falsis **nominibus** imperium", pas "**nomibus**"

Answer (score 1):

C'est vraiment une question de grammaire comparative ... sans réponse depuis six jours !

Pourquoi les anglophones ont-ils mille et une façon de cuisiner le mot *get* ?

Le français écrit, est passé par le latin puis le *latin de cuisine* assaisonné par des moines qui introduisaient les particularismes locaux.

La francophonie s'est construite sur l'émotion des hommes traduites en phonèmes qui restent sensible dans les différents accents qui perdurent après les normalisations faites par les rois ou les constitutions centralisateurs des régionalismes puissants et parfois hostiles.

Mais dans les campagnes, le patois était la seule langue, le *vieux françois* était la marque du bourgeois, jusque parfois, au début du XX° siècle.

Les éditeurs y ont ajouté leur problème de casse : si on n'a pas de *è*, et bien on met *e* + *tt* pour charrette.

L'Académie française a pris sur le tard tout ce qui lui tombait sous la main et, selon que les puissants venaient d'une région ou d'une autre, gravait dans le marbre les particularismes, y compris des mots venus de la perfide Albion.

La langue est vivante par l'usage qu'on en fait, et la normalisation grammairienne ne résiste pas aux SMS, aux ré-inventions perpétuelles des générations qui veulent marquer leur particularité pour ne pas ressembler aux *[bourgeois](http://memoirechante.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/jacques-brel-les-bourgeois/)*.

Answer (score 1):

La bonne traduction de « Quid est hoc ? » est « Qu'est-ce ? » (= quoi est ça ?).
« Qu'est-ce c'est que ça » est un barbarisme absolument impossible à expliquer aussi bien aux non-francophones qu'aux francophones.

Par ailleurs, de très nombreux verbes sont classés ensemble : mordre=tordre ; mourir=courir ; etc. Attention aux doubles comptes, les verbes du 3ème groupe pourraient tout à fait être beaucoup moins nombreux qu'annoncé par WP.

Answer (score 1):

La grammaire française n'est pas plus compliquée que la latine, l'absence de déclinaison est une énorme simplification, mais qui oblige à utiliser un ordre plus strict des mots dans la phrase et des mots de liaison supplémentaires afin d'éviter les ambiguïtés.

Les verbes irréguliers, pour leur part, sont certes une bizarrerie, mais il faut savoir que les mots qui se transforment le plus sont, en général, ceux qui sont les plus utilisés, il faut sans doute y voir la trace d'une certaine richesse dans le vocabulaire courant du français.

L'orthographe française est quant à elle une reconstruction faite en grande partie par l'Académie française pour faire apparaître l'étymologie des mots dans leur orthographe, le même mouvement a eu lieu en anglais, mais pas en italien ou en espagnol.

Par ailleurs quand on compare le français avec les autres langues, il faut aussi se rendre compte que le français est essentiellement la langue d'une région française, alors que l'allemand, l'espagnol et l'italien sont des unifications de dialectes et ont donc subit des simplifications artificielles qui n'ont pas eu lieu en français.